# Correct SSH login and commands for Azure bitnami server

Tags: mongodb, azure, command-line, ssh, terminal

I have a MEAN stack bitnami server setup on Azure. I'm trying to access it through SSH but having permission issues.

I connect through terminal like so:

```
ssh azureuser@<my-host>
```

Then enter my password when prompted. That seems to connect me fine. Next I try and do something like run mongo and ask it to show the database list:

```
mongo
show dbs
```

At this stage I get an error:

```
listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
```

I'm having similar permission issues with other commands. How do I get around this? It's the only login credentials I created when I created the server so I don't see how I can have higher permissions.

Just to confirm, I can access the server and run commands like `mongo` but no further admin commands or editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate to run some commands in mongo, `show dbs` is one of them. Instead of running `mongo`, try

```
mongo admin --username root --password bitnami
```

The default password is **bitnami** for mongo on azure, please change this as soon as you can.

```
db.changeUserPassword("root", "newpassword")
```